# Laravel hasOne through a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

So I have 2 models, User & Profile, the relationship is set up as follows:

```
    /**
     * User belongs to many Profile
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
     */
    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Profile', 'user_profiles');
    }
```

I have 3 tables, users, profiles & user_profiles (the pivot table)

I have a column in my users table called `active_profile` which gets populated with a profile id.

How can I set up the relationship so that I can call something like the following:

`$user->active_profile`

So that it will return all the profile information for the id set in active_profile?

Comment: Did one of the posts below answer your question?

Comment: If the column `active_profile` on `users` table references `id` on `profiles` table - why do you need a pivot to get an active profle model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method into your `User` model like this :

```
public function active_profile ()
{
   return $this->profiles()
          ->find($this->active_profile);
}
```

and then you can call the method as $user->active_profile();

Answer (score 5):

On Laravel 5.8, since I wanted to use it with **eager loading** I used this package: 
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

This was my scenario
A user can be tagged on many photo and a photo can have many users tagged on. I wanted to have a relationship to get the latest photo the user has been tagged on.

I think my scenario can also be applied to any many-to-many relationship

I did the pivot model **UserPhoto**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserPhoto extends Pivot
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function photo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class);
    }

}
```

And then on my **User** model using **staudenmeir**'s package:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasRelationships;

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Photo::class);
    }

    public function latestPhoto()
    {
        return $this->hasOneDeep(Photo::class, [UserPhoto::class])
            ->latest();
    }
}
```

Then I can easily do something like this:

`User::with('latestPhoto')->get()` and `$user->latestPhoto`

---

Edit: 
In an another question, someone asked the same without using a package.
I also provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303547/8068675) that will do the same result.

But after digging deeper, **from both answers, you may avoid the n+1 query, you will still hydrate all the photos from your requested users.** I don't think it's possible to avoid one or the other approach. The cache could be an answer though.

Comment: Amazing.  Thank you!  This might be the most under-rated package in the lara echo system.

Comment: what is 'hasOneDeep'? I'm not finding anything on that.

Comment: @scott This is a method added with the package I have mentionned at the top of the answer. See : https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep#hasonedeep

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but why not just use a `belongsTo` relationship?

```
public function active_profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Profile', 'active_profile');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab the resource using [`find`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

```
$user->profiles()->find($user->active_profile);
```

Comment: Although this works, I was hoping for a more elegant solution, preferably using eloquent relationships.

I will be implementing your solution for the time being but would like to leave the question open to other options for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could add extra field in pivot table, for example `active = enum(y, n)`, then set `unique key (user_id, active)` and then use `wherePivot`method in user model:

```
public function profiles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Profile', 'user_profiles');
}

public function activeProfile()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Profile', 'user_profiles')->wherePivot('active', 'y');
}
```

It requires DB refactoring though.