# Laravel - one-to-one relation through pivot table with eager load

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have this relationship

- A Movement can have multiples steps
- A Step can belongs to multiples Movements

So a had to create a pivot table and a `belongsToMany` relationship, but my pivot table have some extras columns, like `finished` and `order`

I want to have two relationships, one to get all steps from a movement and another one to get the current step from the movement (the last finished step)

I know how to get all steps

```
public function steps()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(MovementStep::class, 'movement_movement_steps')
        ->withPivot('order', 'finished')
        ->orderBy('pivot_order');
}
```

But how about the current step? I need this kind of relationship, but returning only one record and be able to eager load it cause I'm passing it to vue.js

```
public function current_step()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(MovementStep::class, 'movement_movement_steps')
        ->withPivot('order', 'finished')
        ->where('finished', true)
        ->orderBy('pivot_order', 'desc');
}
```

Notice, I'd like to do that without extras packages

*alternative solution, but with extra package:* [Laravel hasOne through a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033777/laravel-hasone-through-a-pivot-table#answer-56832439) (not the answer marked as correct, the answer from @cbaconnier)

Comment: steps is working correctly?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes

Comment: and current_step what is returning?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia it returns all finished steps, I want it to return the first one

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia but I saw that current_step has a mistake, I'll fix it

Comment: so you want to do `$element->with('current_step'); ` ? also if you want to filter the pivot , you should use wherePivot(...)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia, yes, actually I'll use `$with` attribute, but is the same thing

Comment: might this help you? https://laravel.io/forum/05-20-2014-one-to-one-relation-through-pivot-table

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia i saw this article, but is the same as creating a `getCurrentStep` attribute and returning the first from `steps`, don't work with eager load

Comment: My first thought would be to add `->limit(1)` but it's apparently [not supported](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/4918) + you would still ends up with an array instead of the model. However, I haven't looked that much in the [subqueries](https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements) from Laravel ^6. Maybe you could find an alternative there

Comment: MIght be dumb but couldnt you just use ->first()?

Comment: @Collin `->first()` wouln't work with eager load, and I think with subquerie I'd need to reproduce every where, but could work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different approach from the answer provided by @mrhn is to create a custom relationship. Brent from Spatie did an [excellent article](https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-custom-relation-classes) about it

Although my answer will do the exact same queries than the one provided by [staudenmeir's package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) it makes me realized that either you use the package, this answer or @mrhn answer, you may avoid the n+1 queries but you may still ends up will a large amount of hydrated models.

In this scenario, I don't think it's possible to avoid one or the other approach. The cache could be an answer though.

Since I'm not entirely sure about your schema, I will provide my solution using the users-photos example from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033777/laravel-hasone-through-a-pivot-table#answer-56832439).

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Photo::class);
    }

    public function latestPhoto()
    {
        return new \App\Relations\LatestPhotoRelation($this);
    }
}
```

**LastestPhotoRelation.php**

```php
<?php


namespace App\Relations;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Photo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class LatestPhotoRelation extends Relation
{

    /** @var Photo|Builder */
    protected $query;

    /** @var User */
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        parent::__construct(Photo::query(), $user);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addConstraints()
    {
        $this->query
            ->join(
                'user_photo',
                'user_photo.photo_id',
                '=',
                'photos.id'
            )->latest();

            // if you have an ambiguous column name error you can use
            // `->latest('movement_movement_steps.created_at');`
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addEagerConstraints(array $users)
    {
        $this->query
            ->whereIn(
                'user_photo.user_id',
                collect($users)->pluck('id')
            );
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function initRelation(array $users, $relation)
    {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user->setRelation(
                $relation,
                null
            );
        }
        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function match(array $users, Collection $photos, $relation)
    {
        if ($photos->isEmpty()) {
            return $users;
        }

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user->setRelation(
                $relation,
                $photos->filter(function (Photo $photo) use ($user) {
                    return $photo->user_id === $user->id;  // `user_id` came with the `join` on `user_photo`
                })->first() // Photos are already DESC ordered from the query
            );
        }

        return $users;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getResults()
    {
        return $this->query->get();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```php
$users = \App\Models\User::with('latestPhoto')->limit(5)->get();
```

The main difference from Brent's article, is that instead of using a `Collection` we are returning the latest Photo `Model`.

Comment: That answer worked perfect for me, I realize that it would need to be something like that package

Comment: I suggest and edit at `if ($photos->isEmpty()) {` returning null instead of `$users`, but it gives an error, how can be done in that case? cause there is no `current_step` it returns the class name

Comment: What if you replace `Photo::class` with `null` in `initRelation()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a way to [create getters and setters](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators) that act similar to columns in the database. These can perfectly solve your problem and you can append them to your serialization.

So instead your current_step is gonna be an accessor (getter). The syntax is `getCurrentStepAttribute()` for the function which will make it accessible on the `current_step` property. To avoid N + 1, eager load the steps when you retrieve the model(s) with the `with('steps')` method. Which is better than running it as a query, as it will execute N times always.

```
public function getCurrentStepAttribute() {
    return $this->steps
        ->where('finished', true)
        ->sortByDesc('pivot_order')
        ->first();
}
```

Now you can use the append property on the Movement.php class, to include your Eloquent accessor.

```
protected $appends = ['current_step'];
```

Comment: This is a solution, but not the best. I don't know if this will answer the need of @SpaceDogCS, but one issue with this solution, is; What if a movement has like 500 steps ? with 15 movements, it would hydrate 7500+15 models, while we only needs 15+15.

Comment: then do it with a query, but then you will have the query running N times

Comment: I guess it could work with this solution, if you did filtering on the with include?

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it doesn't work with eager load, you cant eager load based on a relationship, I've tried